# How to serialize/deserialize Kotlin enum class with constructor to json

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, gson

I am trying to save an enum class to Room db. My class is;

```
enum class TestClass(val firstField: String, secondField: Long) {
    FIRST("test", 1L),
    SECOND("test_2", 2L),
    THIRD("test_3", 3L)
}
```

My TypeConverters are;

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToTestClassList(json: String) = Gson().fromJson<MutableSet<TestClass>>(json)

    @TypeConverter
    fun testClassToJson(testClassSet: MutableSet<TestClass>?) = Gson().toJson(testClassSet)
```

When I save it to room, it shows only enums, not enum's constructors. For example, if list has 2 enums, it saves like

```
["FIRST", "SECOND"]
```

How can I achieve to serialize and deserialize to keep constructor parameters like,

```
[{FIRST, "test", 1L}, {SECOND, "test_2", 2L}]
```

Or something like that to get constructor parameters back.

**UPDATE:**

I've figure it out; I just created new class and in TypeConverter I converted my enum to class that new class I've just created.

```
    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToTestClassList(json: String): MutableSet<TestClass>? {
        return Gson().fromJson<List<TestClassDatabase>?>(json)?.map {
            it.testClass.apply {
                firstField = it.firstField
            }
        }?.toMutableSet()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun testClassToJson(testClassList: MutableSet<TestClass>?): String {
        return Gson().toJson(testClassList?.run {
            mutableListOf<TestClassDatabase>().apply {
                addAll(testClassList.map {
                    TestClassDatabase(it, it.firstField)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

Not my proudest code tho, but you get the point.